# Hibernate and SQL Server - time mismatch between Java and database with Java 8 types

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, datetime

I got the following situation. My software operates on a database with tables autogenerated by Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009. The database runs on an MS SQL Server 2012. We created a new table in NAV that has several datetime fields. NAV stores these to SQL Server using `datetime` columns (I know this tyoe should not be used today, but NAV 2009 does and I can't change that).

My software receives data from external partners and writes it into this table, so that NAV can read it and work on it. NAV only reads that table, never writes to it.

But for some reason weird things happen when storing the time values to the database. My software is a Spring Boot 5.1 application that uses Hibernate 5.3.7 for ORM. My JPA entity uses the Java 8 type `Instant` to map the date and time values to the database table.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Nav Company$My Table")
public class MyTableEntity implements Serializable {

    /* some more fields here... */

    @Column(name = "Our Timestamp", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Instant ourTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "Partner Timestamp", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Instant partnerTimestamp;

    /* getters and setters here */
}
```

When data from a partner comes in, my software reads the provided timestamp as `LocalDateTime`, adds timezone information to it to get a `ZonedDateTime`,  extracts the `Instant` and stores it in the database using the entity.

My logs show that the time calculation in the software is correct. The last line is the `Instant` that is written to the database.

```
2019-01-22 09:00:01 [...] : navTimestamp[LDT]: ldt =    2019-01-22T09:00:01.015597300
2019-01-22 09:00:01 [...] : navTimestamp[LDT]: zoneId = Europe/Berlin
2019-01-22 09:00:01 [...] : navTimestamp[LDT]: zdt =    2019-01-22T09:00:01.015597300+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
2019-01-22 09:00:01 [...] : navTimestamp[ZDT]: zdt =     2019-01-22T09:00:01.015597300+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
2019-01-22 09:00:01 [...] : navTimestamp[ZDT]: instant = 2019-01-22T08:00:01.015597300Z
```

But when I `SELECT` the data from the table using SQL Server Management Studio, it shows that the database stored `2019-01-22 09:00:01.017` instead of `2019-01-22 08:00:01.017` as I would have expected (remember: column type is `datetime`, not `datetimeoffset`). When NAV reads that value, it even adds another hour to convert it into local time (GMT+1), thus showing `2019-01-22 10:00:01`.

So I guess somewhere between my application and the SQL Server, Hibernate does some weird things and does not transmit the UTC time stored in the `Instant` but instead converts it to local time first and then stores it in the database.

How can I make sure that the UTC time is stored in the database and not local time?

Comment: the instant looses the zone info. Datetime does not support zones afaik. You need to write and read utc.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks for the hint, just testing that solution now